# Wordpress migration to Windows Shared server redirects to old directory

Tags: wordpress, iis

So I am deploying a WordPress site to a shared Windows Cloud hosting platform. Server limitations prevent me from using most migration plugins (Duplicator doesn't work as any process longer than 30 seconds is killed stone dead, thank you HostGator). I have managed to migrate most of the website manually, but the home page always redirects to the folder I stored it in while developing in xampp, so the url for the home page always redirects to *http://example.com/devfolder* instead of just *http://example.com*, resulting in a 404. All the other pages work, though. *http://example.com/about-us* and similar pages are all working properly. It's just the home page that has problems.

Here is what I have looked at so far:

From the database, all url entries in `wp_options` have `http://example.com` without the extraneous folder

From the dashboard under *Settings->General*, The WordPress Address and Site Address are both `http://example.com`

From the .htaccess file (not that it matters much here):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

From the web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="WordPress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <clear />
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have even used the Better Search Replace plugin (Dashboard works too) to replace all instances of `localhost:8080/devfolder` with `example.com`.

I don't see any reason why the site keeps appending the */devfolder* on the home page url. Any thoughts?

Comment: None of the settings you shared leads to the redirection. So it must be caused by something else. Have you tried to remove all WordPress extensions and install them back one by one?

Comment: 1. Change url from database and after that goto permalink and click to save permalink. Dont do anything with htaccess as htaccess will be managed itself.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I am retarded. My browser cached the redirect so when I fixed the issue, it redirected regardless. Issue was fixed when I cleared my the browser cache.